# MySQL: Performance of multiple INSERTS

Tags: mysql, performance

We are running an application that uses MySQL. We have two instances test and production.

The problem is about the performance of multiple INSERTS. Say we are inserting 200 records into the same table, we have two options from our application:

1. We can consecutively fire 200 INSERT statements to the DB server.
2. We fire one stamement with 200 VALUE blocks.

Obviously option 2 should be much better in performance. However we observe the following:

- On test server both options run performant, while option 2 is slightly better. This is what we expected.
- On production server only option 2 runs performant, while option 1 is significantly slower (by factor 100).

We are wondering how this can happen. Taking the MySQL documentation into account (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html), one significant performance factor of inserting is connecting and sending the queries. So our first suspicion was a configuration glitch on the production server.

We are using mysqli to connect to the servers. On test and production application and DB are hosted on the same machine. What we already tried:

- Switching between TCP and UNIX on both servers
- Defining a default MySQL socket in php.ini instead of explicitly passing it at connection time.

With no remarkable change in performance. Maybe someone has a hint on what it is worth to check.

Update: The hardware is similar and data on both servers are in sync.

Comment: how do the test and prod Servers compare on Hardware side?

Comment: I believe the database data might be vary from Test server to Production server. Production server might have large number of records than Test server. It also may impact performance.

Comment: Are both tables set to the same engine? (InnoDB, MyISAM, ...)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  This may provide clues (engines, datatypes, indexes, number of unique keys, etc.)  Also, were the 200 rows provide in PK order?  Was the production server doing stuff with the table at the same time as the test?